# Can I use @Viewbag... inside of webgrid column ActionLink format instead of hard-coding the name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid, actionlink

I have several pages to link to depending on the user level.
Sample: level 1 goes to pageA, level 2 goes to pageB, etc.
Inside of the controller, I set Viewbag.page to which page.

When the webgrid is creating the column below, is there a way to replace "actionName" with the content of Viewbag.page?

```
@grid.GetHtml(
columns: grid.Columns(
grid.Column("filename", format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink((string)item.filename, "actionName", "controllerName", new { id = item.id}, null) </text> ),
```

Comment: You mean to say,
instead of hardcoding "ActionName" it should populate dynamically based on level?

Comment: HEGDE, Yes.  That's what I mean.  Sorry I didn't make it clear.  I should have go to bed instead of trying to work at 2am.

Answer (score 1):

If you are redirecting from controller then better go for TempData instead of ViewBag since ViewBag will be null after POST.

here is a code snippet for using dynamic data in cshtml:

```
@{ 

var actionName = TempData["actionName"];
}

@Html.ActionLink((string)item.filename, actionName, "controllerName", new { id = item.id }, null) )
```

you should set value for `TempData["actionName"];` from controller based on your level.